# How is the function $\psi(c) = (c\bmod m,c\bmod n)$, given $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, a bijection?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I came across this lemma in a textbook, and found something in the proof I did not understand:

**Proof that  $\psi$ is injective:**
Assume otherwise, that there exists a value in the co-domain that has more than one pre-image:
$$\psi(c) = \psi(c')$$
By its definition, $\psi(c) = (c\mod m,c\mod n)$, given $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, so it follows:
$$c \bmod m = c' \bmod\ m \iff c \equiv c' \pmod m$$
$$c \bmod n = c' \bmod\ n \iff c \equiv c' \pmod n$$

By definition of a congruence modulo x:
$$c \equiv c' \pmod m \iff m\ |\ (c - c')$$
$$c \equiv c' \pmod n \iff n\ |\ (c - c')$$

Given that $m, n$ are relatively-prime ( $\gcd(m,n)=1$ ), it follows that:
$$mn \mid(c - c')\iff c \equiv c' \pmod {mn}$$

Then, the text concludes that $c = c'$ from the above congruence, which I don't understand. Given that $c, c' \in \mathbb N$, I don't see why $c - c'$ must equal $0$.

I even have a counterexample to this reasoning. If we take $m=2, n=3$, which are relatively prime, we see that $\psi(7) = \psi(13) = \psi(6k + 1) = (1, 1)$, showing that $(1,1)$ in the co-doman has multiple pre-images.

If the proof is indeed incorrect, is there any way to show if $\psi$ is a bijection?

Comment: What is the function? If the domain is $\Bbb Z$, then $\psi$ is definitely not injective. If the domain is $\Bbb Z/(m,n)$, then it is a bijection.

Comment: The domain should be numbers modulo $mn$! Then your counterexample is no longer a problem:$7 \equiv 1 \bmod 6$.

Comment: When you speak of bijections, you need to be very clear of "from what" and "to what".  Here, $\psi: \mathbb Z\big /mn\mathbb Z \to  \mathbb Z\big /m\mathbb Z\,\times \, \mathbb Z\big /n\mathbb Z$ and, as such, it is a bijection.  Note that $7$ and $13$ represent the same element in $\mathbb Z\big /6\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ah, yes - y'all figured it out. There was an errata stating the domain should be $\mathbb Z/mn\mathbb Z$ rather than the natural numbers. Thus, 7, 13, etc. would essentially be the same number modulo n. This solves the little confusion - thanks!